# Flink streaming job is not scaling as expected

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are in the middle of testing scaling ability of Flink. But we found that scaling not working, no matter increase more slot or increase number of Task Manager. We would expect a linear, if not close-to-linear scaling performance but the result even show degradation. Appreciated any comments.

Test Details,

-VMWare vsphere

-Just a simple pass through test,

```
- auto gen source 3mil records, each 1kb in size, parallelism=1

- source pass into next map operator, which just return the same record, and sent counter to statsD, parallelism is in cases = 2,4,6
```

- 3 TM, total 6 slots(2/TM) each JM/TM has 32 vCPU, 100GB memory
- Result:

  - 2 slots: 26 seconds, 3mil/26=115k TPS
  - 4 slots: 23 seconds, 3mil/23=130k TPS
  - 6 slots: 22 seconds, 3mil/22=136k TPS

As shown the scaling is almost nothing. Any clue? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code? It's hard to comment on perf problems w/o knowing exactly what's being done. But limiting the source to a parallelism of one is going to put a limit on the scalability.

Answer (score 0):

please refer to the sample code,

```
    public class passthru extends RichMapFunction<String, String> {
        public void open(Configuration configuration) throws Exception {
        ... ... 
            stats = new NonBlockingStatsDClient();
        }
        public String map(String value) throws Exception { 
            ... ...
            stats.increment(); 
            return value;
        }
    }

    public class datagen extends RichSourceFunction<String> {
        ... ...
        public void run(SourceContext<String> ctx) throws Exception {
            int i = 0;
            while (run){
                String idx = String.format("%09d", i);
                ctx.collect("{\"<a 1kb json content with idx in certain json field>\"}");
                i++;
                if(i == loop) 
                    run = false;
            }
        }
        ... ...
    }
    public class Job {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ... ...
            DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(new datagen(loop)).rebalance();
            DataStream<String> convert = stream.map(new passthru(statsdUrl));
            env.execute("Flink");
        } 
    }
```

the reductionState code,

```
    dataStream.flatMap(xxx).keyBy(new KeySelector<xxx, AggregationKey>() {
        public AggregationKey getKey(rec r) throws Exception {
            ... ...             
           }
        }).process(new Aggr());

    public class Aggr extends ProcessFunction<rec, rec> {
        private ReducingState<rec> store;
        public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
            store= getRuntimeContext().getReducingState(new ReducingStateDescriptor<>(
                "reduction store", new ReduceFunction<rec>() {
            ... ...
        }
    public void processElement(rec r, Context ctx, Collector<rec> out)
        throws Exception {
            ... ...
            store.add(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should be using a [RichParallelSourceFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/source/RichParallelSourceFunction.html). If you care about making the records from different instances of the source distinct, you can get ahold of each instance's index from the [RuntimeContext](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/RuntimeContext.html#getIndexOfThisSubtask--), which is available via the getRuntimeContext() method in the RichFunction interface.

Also, Flink has a built-in [statsd metrics reporter](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/metrics.html#statsd-orgapacheflinkmetricsstatsdstatsdreporter) that you should be using instead of rolling your own. Moreover, numRecordsIn, numRecordsOut, numRecordsInPerSecond, and numRecordsOutPerSecond are [already being computed for you](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/metrics.html#io), so no need to create this instrumentation yourself. You can also access these metrics via Flink's web interface, or the REST API.

As for why you might be experiencing poor scalability with the Kafka consumer, there are many things that could cause this. If you are using event time processing, then idle partitions could be holding things up (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-5479). If the stream is keyed, then data skew could be an issue. If you are connecting to an external database or service, then it could easily be a bottleneck. If checkpointing is misconfigured it could cause this. Or insufficient network capacity.

I would start to debug this by looking at some key metrics in the Flink web UI. Is the load well balanced across the sub-tasks, or is it skewed? You could turn on latency tracking and see if one of the kafka partitions is misbehaving (by inspecting the latency at the sink(s), which will be reported on a per-partition basis). And you could look for back pressure.

Comment: after change to RichParallelSourceFunction, the sample program working much better now. But we still need advice because FlinkKafkaConsumer011 still not able to scale which already using RichParallelSourceFunction. Any tips?

Comment: And we always set kafka partition = total TM #slot. But the result is still capped and not improve linearly.

Comment: Thanks for tips! To isolate kafka from the root cause, data generator source is used instead but scaling is still not working. 2 slots scale to 4 slots works, 4 slots to 8 slots also works, but 16 slots, 32 slots and so on is all capped at around 30k TPS. 4 TM(32 vCPU, 30 GB memory), 16 slots/TM. Source is generated evenly to slots. No external service, no checkpoint yet. After investigate, ReducingState is the reason, without it scaling is working in much better way. Any idea? thanks. (please refer the relevant code above, when this line exists the scaling get affected: "store.add(r);")

Comment: I guess it might related to hdfs statebackend we used, when too many record store into state. Even though we have enough memory, and check-pointing is disable, do you think rocksdb would help?

Comment: A couple of questions: Do you have an unbounded key space, and perhaps an ever-increasing amount of state due to the appearance of new keys? Are you using timers, perhaps lots of timers (e.g. to expire state)?

Comment: yes the app keep storing record object into the reduction store with unique key. The app work as a aggregator, store same key record and merge with customize aggregation function. in this performance test, all record is stored into the state with different key, and each of them create a timer. In real case, the timer function will flush the record from state store. the state size is around 10GB. Understand this is a large state so we are going to move to rocksdb in production. But for the testing now, hdfs as statebackend, and check-pointing is disable. Any advice? Is this a proper approach?

Comment: forget to mentioned CPU,RAM and disk storage is sufficient